# How do I overlap plots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I was wondering how I overlap these two graphs in matplotlib. One is a plot with dots, the other one named 'trendlijn' is a linear line.

I've tried to use alpha but it didn't work. Does someone have a suggestion for me?
I am not that good in programming, so please, take your time to explain the steps you've made, thanks.

Here's the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import linregress
import numpy as np
d01 = [200, 180, 160, 140, 120]
di1 = [122, 130, 143, 165, 204]

d02 = [200, 180, 160, 140, 120]
di2 = [78, 82, 85, 95, 107]

multiply_y = np.multiply(d01, di1)
print(multiply_y)

add_x = np.add(d01, di1)
print(add_x)

a, b, r, p, s_a = linregress(add_x, multiply_y)
print ('Richtingcoëfficent=' ,a ,'\n','Standaardafwijking van het gemiddelde=', s_a*3, '\n', 'Snijpunt Y-as=', b)
plt.plot([add_x[0],add_x[-1]],[a*add_x[0]+b,a*add_x[-1]+b], label='trendlijn')
plt.plot(add_x, multiply_y, 'o', label='Metingen')
plt.grid(b=None, which='major', axis='both')
plt.xlabel('$x = d0 + di$ ($m$)')
plt.ylabel('$y = d0*d1$ ($m$)')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

Comment: Note that seaborn's [regplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) (`sns.regplot(add_x, multiply_y)`) could also generate a nice visualization combining scatterplot, regression line and a confidence interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_x[0]` is not the smallest number in your list and `add_x[-1]` is not the biggest. So your code do not cover all range of values. You can use `min(add_x)` and `max(add_x)` instead.

```
plt.plot([min(add_x), max(add_x)],[a*min(add_x)+b, a*max(add_x)+b], label='trendlijn')
```